# Can try catch be used this way to handle exceptions?

Tags: php, laravel, exception, try-catch

`Try catch` is used for handling exceptions but could it be used this way too?

```
private $blockUrl = [];   

public function doSomething($urls) {
    try {
        foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
            if (in_array($url, $this->blockUrl)) continue;
            $meta[$url] = get_meta_tags($url);
            unset($urls[$key]);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->blockUrl[] = $url;
        return $this->doSomething($urls);
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

So basically what this does is that it gets the meta tags of the urls passed on to the method. Then should an exception on the `get_meta_tags` occur, an exception will be thrown and that url that caused the exception will be put into an array `$this->blockUrl`. Then it will call the same method again but this time, only the remaining urls will be validated again.

Is this a correct and efficient way to do this logic?

I used `try catch` here because of sometimes I get `curl` errors on the `get_meta_tags` and I just want to skip  those urls that has those errors and continue with the flow.

Comment: Does curl actually throw an *exception*...?! Or just display an error/notice? The latter can't be `caught`.

Comment: @deceze - In PHP 7 you can catch it as `Throwable`.

Comment: Yes, it works and I want to know if this is a good practice or is there a better way to handle this.

Comment: How about putting your try/catch inside the foreach loop, and just put continue in the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in my comment, you can do the error checking inside the loop, and just skip over any bad ones. This allows you to get rid of the `$blockUrl` array, unless you need it elsewhere.

```
public function doSomething($urls) {
    $meta = array();
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
        try {
            $result = get_meta_tags($url);
            $meta[$url] = $result;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return $meta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `try/catch` inside the loop:

```
public function doSomething($urls) {
    $meta = [];

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        try {
            $meta[$url] = get_meta_tags($url);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            //
        }
    }

    return $meta;
}
```

Don't forget to initialize the `$meta` array, otherwise you might get an errer when you try to return an undefined variable.